# Can I reverse the direction on DrawRectangle/FillRectangle in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graph, coordinates

I need to make a graph using Visual Studio in C#, but when I set the points like so:

```
g.DrawRectangle(pen, 10, 300, 30, 400)
```

My rectangle obviously flies off the panel, since in C# the height increases downwards, is there a way to fix this? I can't just set the starting point higher up and have it move downwards because the program I'm writing needs to take in data.

P.S. I understand there is an easier way to draw graphs in C#, but this is for a school assignment and I'm only allowed to use the DrawRectangle or FillRectangle features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move  the `Graphics`  object down and mirror it like this:

```
 g.TranslateTransform(0, Height);
 g.ScaleTransform(1, -1);
```

Now you can draw upwards:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 10, 300, 30, 400);
```

Note that here `Height` is the `Form.Height`. If you draw on anything else, (including a `Bitmap`) you need to use its height instead!

And if you don't want to start at the very bottom simply use a smaller number..!

Comment: Thank you so much, you've saved me hours of banging my head against the keyboard.